# Bind list to gridview including buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to bind a list of objects to gridview. The object needs to contain a column of buttons. Some of these buttons need to be disabled depending on the data in the list.

Is it possible to generate a list of objects including the enabled or disabled buttons and simply bind to the `gridview`?

Comment: what do you want to do with your button?

Comment: You can use [TemplateFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx)

Comment: if the user presses the button on a specific row then one of the cells text is updated on the row and that particular button needs to be disabled.

Comment: i dont think i can use templatefields as i need to be able to disable a specific button as described above. If i can then please let me know. Even if i can binding directly from a list of objects would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add button in `gridview` `itemtemplate` like this :

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" 
     Text="click" Enabled="<%# Eval('IsButtonEnabled') %>"/>
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

then you can add `Flag` as `bool`  variable in your datasource and set your desired values , `true` to enable , `false` to disable

**Edit** , for example you have datasource like this :

```
class YourDataSource {

public string prop1 {get;set;}
public string prop2 {get;set;}
public bool IsButtonEnabled {get;set;}
}
```

if `IsButtonEnabled` is true so button will be enabled else it will be disabled

Comment: hi, can you give an example of "then you can add Flag as bool variable in your datasource and set your desired values , true to enable , false to disable" using code behind (C#) - It sounds like this may be the answer

Comment: ok , I mean , In your datasource , add a new property of type `bool` to detect if the button disabled or not , then bind this property to the button `Enabled` property

Answer (score 1):

Having a flag is a good approach but remember that you need someway to actually store the state of your flag and rebind it every time the data changes. I've chose `ViewState` for this demo, here's the complete example:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployees" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Update" Enabled='<%# Eval("AllowUpdate") %>' OnClick="Update" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            BindData();
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        if (ViewState["Employees"] == null)
        {
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee{Name="Employee 1", AllowUpdate = true},
            new Employee{Name="Employee 2", AllowUpdate = true}
        };

            gvEmployees.DataSource = employees;
            ViewState["Employees"] = employees;
        }

        else
        {
            List<Employee> employees  = ViewState["Employees"] as List<Employee>;
            gvEmployees.DataSource = employees;
        }

        gvEmployees.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button update = sender as Button;
        if (update != null & !String.IsNullOrEmpty(update.CommandArgument))
        {
            string employeeName = update.CommandArgument;

            List<Employee> employees = ViewState["Employees"] as List<Employee>;
            Employee emp = employees.Where(em => em.Name == employeeName).FirstOrDefault();
            emp.Name = "some new value...";
            emp.AllowUpdate = false;

            //Rebind the grid with the new values
            ViewState["Employees"] = employees;
            BindData();
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool AllowUpdate { get; set; }
}
```